# Display Flash Error Messages to User After Mongoose Model Save

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug, router

I have a page `index.js` which has a form to add users, and beside it a list of users in the database.

### /routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../schemas/user');

router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
  var user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('user save error ' + err.errmsg);
      return res.json(err.errmsg);
    }
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  User.find(function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('get error ' + err);
      //return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    res.render(
      'index',
      {
        userList : users
      }
    );
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

### /schemas/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  group: String,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});

var User = mongoose.model(
  'User',
  userSchema
);

module.exports = User;
```

Here is my view:

### /views/index.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}

  .container
    .row
      .col-sm
        h1 Create User
        form(
          method='POST'
          action='/create'
        )
          .form-group
            label(for='username') Username:
            input#username.form-control(
              type='text',
              placeholder='Enter username...',
              name='username'
            )
            if usernameError
              p.error= usernameError
          .form-group
            label(for='password') Password:
            input#password.form-control(
              type='password',
              placeholder='Enter password...',
              name='password'
            )
            if passwordError
              p.error= passwordError
          .form-group
            label(for='email') Email:
            input#email.form-control(
              type='email',
              placeholder='Enter email...',
              name='email'
            )
            if emailError
              p.error= emailError
          button.btn.btn-primary(
            type='submit',
          ) Submit
      .col-sm
        h2 User List
        ul
          each user in userList
            li= user.username
```

As you can see, I have some conditionals in my `index.pug` file. What I want to do is if an error occurs I want to assign a message to a variable based on the error type (i.e. username already taken, or password too short) and pass that variable over to my pug view. The view will then render the message **if** the proper variable is set. Can somebody help me out? I'm mostly struggling with the fact that I also have to render the list of users, if I try to find users within the error catching part of the post node complains about headers already being set, i.e. If I have my router.post function like so:

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
  var user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('user save error ' + err.errmsg);
      User.find(function (err2, users) {
        if (err2) {
          console.log('get error ' + err2);
          //return res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        res.render(
          'index',
          {
            userList : users,
            usernameError: err.errmsg
          }
        );
      });
    }
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

Then I expect to see the usernameError message filled in my view but instead I get an error from the node server:

```
user save error E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: username_1 dup key: { : "John" }
POST /create 302 71.995 ms - 46
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
```

it's because unique true.

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Error  because you haven't return error. Whenever error occure simply return like

```
 if (err) return next(err)
```

provided that you are using express centralized error handler 
check  last lines of your app.js.All errors from next(err) goes here

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.error( err);
..............
});
```